# iOS10 app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data

Tags: ios, video, camera, privacy

My app crashed when I try to open video camera. It is fine when it opens the camera, but when I switch from image to video I get this error:

```
[access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

I find this weird because I have added the permission in my plist file.

[image]

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Camera is used to make pictures when creating a job</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.plist` add this key: `Privacy - Microphone Usage Description` and your desired value.

[image]